# Changing table name of command using raster2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

I am completely newbie with GIS and PostGIS as well

I'm trying to load raster into postgreSQL with raster2pgsql. It runs well.

However, the table name of the raster is generated automatically. For example, the raster named: landsat.tiff, then the table name is landsat.

Can we change that name of table? and how we can do it?

Here's what I typed in Windows Command line:

```
\raster2pgsql -s 4326 *.TIFF -t 100x100 > demo.sql
```

and insert into database

```
\psql -U postgres -d demo -f demo.sql
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you need to type in Windows command line:

```
\raster2pgsql -s 4326 *.TIFF -t 100x100 table_name > demo.sql
```